# How can I fill treeview with visual.net from db (access)

Tags: treeview, fill

How to Populate treeview  Control in Visual Basic (VB.NET)
 from db (access)

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on your data. In general, you need to create a TreeView first and then populate it with nodes. I did that in C# once which is similar to VB. The [documentation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=TreeView&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4) of Microsoft is quite helpful. In C# you would start with something like this:

```
var myTreeView = new TreeView();
myTreeView.Nodes.Add("root");
```

This would create a TreeView with one node. The `Nodes` property is a list of child nodes. Every `TreeNode` also has this property, so you can use it combined with indexing to select the node you want. f.e. `myTreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("child")` would add a child node to the root node.